# What's it called when a character replies to something said in the previous scene?

Tags: terminology, attack-on-titan

Example: in *Attack on Titan* S4E28 (16 minutes and 45 seconds in) Eren tells Floch his plan and then we see a cut to Historia telling Eren that he shouldn't do it (in an entirely different place, although it is implied that he said the same thing to her because of how quickly the scene changes).

Is there a term for this? More generally: is there a term for conversations that happen "between" scenes?

Comment: The trope for this is called [Twisted Echo Cut](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TwistedEchoCut), unless it's a question-response, in which case it's an [Answer Cut](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnswerCut).  I don't know if it has an official term of art though.

Comment: @DavidW Post that as an answer with some quotes of the most relevant parts in case the links go down, and that'd be a decent answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known in TVTropes as [Two Scenes, One Dialogue](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TwoScenesOneDialogue)

> A mode of exposition where the camera switches between two groups of people as they receive the same information.
> Lines of dialogue carry across the two scenes, sometimes to the point of the two scenes answering the other's questions or even Finishing Each Other's Sentences.

The description continues further down:

> Anime often mixes this with Inaction Sequence and the Combat Commentator. It's not uncommon for characters scattered far and wide to have the exact same conversation, explaining what's happening to the audience.

This particular example is not listed in the Anime/Manga examples of this trope but I think it fits particularly well